# How do I plot a function with a scale that has power of 2 increments?

Tags: matlab

I have a set of data say `x=1:100` and `y=x.^2` how do I plot this so that the line is linear and the scale increases by the power of 2?

Comment: Why don't you try plotting log(y) and change the tick labels.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [loglog plotting function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loglog.html) is what you are looking for:

x = 1:100;
y = x.^2;
loglog(x,y);

[image: Output]